# Jenkins cloud : ImportError: No module named selenium (Python)

Tags: python, selenium, shell, jenkins

I run a junkins on cloud version

I have this config on the Script shell, I am getting this error :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

export https_proxy=http://proxy-internet-aws-us.subsidia.org:3128

export http_proxy=http://proxy-internet-aws-us.subsidia.org:3128

python3 -m venv venv

pip install -r requirements.txt

echo "Import chromedriver on the env variable."

export CHROMEWEBDRIVER=/usr/local/bin/chromedriver

echo "Import python path on the env variable."

export PYTHONPATH=.

python  com/decathlon/POMProject/Tests/Login/loginTest.py
```

And i have this error message on Console Output :

```
Import chromedriver on the env variable.

Import python path on the env variable.

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "com/decathlon/POMProject/Tests/Login/loginTest.py", line 6, in <module>
    from selenium import webdriver

ImportError: No module named selenium

Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure

Xvfb stopping

Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by adding Chromedriver in the right place :

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

export https_proxy=http://proxy.org:1212
export http_proxy=http://proxy.org:31212

python3 -m venv venv
source ./venv/bin/activate
pip3 install -r requirements.txt

echo "Import chromedriver on the env variable."
export CHROMEWEBDRIVER=/usr/local/bin/chromedriver

echo "Import python path on the env variable."
export PYTHONPATH=.

python  com/POMProject/Reports/testSuite1.py
```